# Organize texts in a file

Tags: php, list, loops, for-loop

I want to organize the texts in a file so if the texts in two or more lines are same, I want to keep them together.

Example:

```
US
CA
US
```

Would change to:

```
US
US
CA
```

I looked around, but couldn't find an answer really.

I can get the file to open with this:

```
$file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    // do same stuff with the $line
}
fclose($file);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you getting the text from? Can it be sorted before you add to a text file?

Comment: I am getting the text from a text file so it is unorganized on the text file

Comment: Read the text from the file into an array, sort the array and then write it back out to a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $line);
// sorts it alphabetically
sort($pieces, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Sounds like it should do the trick.